# Dynamic server name using variable in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am using a csv file to load the data into jmeter.
Also, a part of the sever name is stored in the same csv file.

I need to create the sever name something like this:

```
${usernameInCSV}.twitter.com
```

The above syntax is not working for me. In solutions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You syntax looks correct.

Check the CSV DataSet configuration (can you show yours?):

- You have set variables (one of them is usernameInCSV) are separated by comma in the element configuration
- you have set separator and it matches the one in csv file